# Вывод гласных из двух самых длинных слов

Tags: c++

Как написать часть программы, которая будет находить два максимальных по длинне слова, и выводить гласные буквы (без повторений), которые встретились в них. Символами могут быть только заглавные латинские буквы

Вот, что уже есть:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(array < System::String ^ >^args)
{

    set < char >simbols;
    set < char >digits;
    char *s1 = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
        simbols.insert(s1[i]);
    }

    int n = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo slov (ne bolee 10): ";
        cin >> n;
        if ((n <= 0) || (n > 10)) // количество слов
            cout << "Oshibka vvoda" << endl;
    }

    while ((n <= 0) || (n > 10));
    char strs[10][80];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Vvedite slovo: ";
        cin >> strs[i];
        cout << strs[i] << " slovo " << endl;
        int tmp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(strs[i]); j++) {
            if (simbols.count(strs[i][j]) == 1) {
                //гласные E Y U I O A

            } else
            {
                cout << "Vstretilsa nedopustimii simvol" << endl;
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << " Vivod bykv = ";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @mishel, вот внутри скобочек, где кода пока нет Вам и надо найти 2 самых длинных (это у которых strlen(strs[i]) самые большие) слова и запомнить их индексы (в этом месте это i) в переменных, скажем, m1 и m2.

Потом напишите функцию, которая выводит гласные без повторения из слова и вызовите ее один раз с strs[m1], а другой c strs[m2]. 

И задача решена.

Comment: Если Вам не составит труда можите это написать, а то уже голова кругом идет =(

Comment: Вот, что у меня есть по поиску двух максимальных элементов, но результаты он выдает как то странно, или просто написал неправильно

    int m1 = 0, m2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strlen(strs[i]) > m1) {
     m1 = strlen(strs[i]);
        }
    
        else if (strlen(strs[i]) != m1) {
     if (strlen(strs[i]) > m2) {
         m2 = strlen(strs[i]);
     }
        }
    }
    
    cout << "  VIVOD SLOV  " << m1 << ' ' << m2 << endl;

Comment: @mishel, изучите ответ, который написал Вам @alexlz.

А потом примените тот же алгоритм не к string (это у @alexlz) а к Вашим char[].

Comment: Чето я все равно не разобрался =/

Answer (score 3):

Без проверок, считая, что весь ввод корректен:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string s[2] = {"", ""};
    char v[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'};
    set<char> vowels (v, v+sizeof v);
    while(!cin.eof()) {
        string w;
        cin >> w;
        if(w.length() > s[0].length()) {
            s[1] = s[0];
            s[0] = w;
        } else if (w.length() > s[1].length()) {
            s[1] = w;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        cout << "Слово " << i << "(" << s[i] << ")> ";
        set<char> v1;
        for(string::iterator it = s[i].begin(); it < s[i].end(); it++) 
            if(vowels.find(*it) != vowels.end()) 
                v1.insert(*it);
        for(set<char>::iterator it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); it++)
            cout << *it << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @alexlz, вот меня всегда интересует, с какой целью вместо

    string ts = "abc";
    for (int i = 0; i < ts.length(); i++)
      cout << ts[i] << '\n';

пишут (ну, `std::` к Вашему примеру не относится, это для пущего эффекта)

    std::string ts("abc");
    for(std::string::iterator it = ts.begin(); it < ts.end(); it++)
      std::cout << *it << '\n';


IMHO это просто "ученость свою" хотят показать.

Comment: Увы, со знанием C++ у меня далеко не всё благополучно, так что объяснить не смогу. Но сам язык является такой страшной мешаниной из C, ООП и ещё много чего, что просто удивительно, что программы на нём ещё работают. И, раз эта конструкция работает у других, то я использовал её. (Я просто боюсь этого языка). Особенно string'и, которые хрен знает из чего состоят: char, wchar, символы переменной длины и пр. Разумеется, операция `[]` должна отрабатывать нормально, но вот что меняющихся условиях жизни должна выдавать .length() -- это ещё вопрос.

Comment: @alexlz, золотые слова (я не шучу). Вот и у меня впечатление (особенно, когда вижу, как начинающие мучаются, пытаясь записать какой-нибудь незамысловатый алгоритм), что С++ не лучший язык для обучения, а если откровенно, то и для практического программирования.

--

.length() должна выдавать *текущую* длину. На практике, зная что по смыслу задачи длина строки не меняется, я напишу

      for (int i = 0, l = ts.length(); i < l; i++) {
          ...
      }

Собственно, даже если длина меняется, лучше писать так, явно изменяя l в цикле, особенно если длина изменяется в функциях вызываемых в for

Comment: Ну, вообще трактовка [`length`][1] неоднозначна.

**Returns a count of the number of characters in the string.**

Количество каких символов? Любых? Однобайтных? Двухбайтных? Или MBCS? Лучше бы написали - "`length` возвращает кол-во однобайтных элементов `char`, из которых состоит `string`"

[1]:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/